# Return a set of SQL Results based on criteria from other tables

Tags: mysql

I wasn't sure how to actually title this question, but if you got in here, I'll try to explain it to the best of my ability.

You can find my SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b81/1).

```
SELECT *
FROM `challenges`
LEFT JOIN `challenges_competitors` ON `challenges_competitors`.`challenge_id` = `challenges`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `challenges_competitors`.`user_id`
WHERE `challenges`.`owner_id` != 3 AND `challenges`.`status` = 'pending'
ORDER BY `challenges`.`id`;
```

Basically what I want to do with the query is return any **challenge** that **user3** does not own or is part of.

There are two tables involved for this. The first table is challenges. This table holds the user id as `owner_id`, as well as the challenge id and some other data. Then there's the challenges_competitors table that holds `challenge_id` and `user_id` to connect that table with both challenges and the users.

When I run the query and join the tables, there are bound to have duplicates because a challenge can have many competitors. So what I want to do is if there is a challenge that the **user3** does not own, but he is part of this challenge, to not get that row back.

I really hope I explained this well. lol

Comment: " to not get that row back" .... is that what you meant to say?

Comment: Yeah, basically that row of the challenges should not be returned because he is "involved" in the challenge as a competitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the most basic information about which challenges (their `id`) aren't being owned by `users.id = 3` and that don't have that user as a competitor altering your query by adding `NOT EXISTS` clause would be sufficient.

```
SELECT c.id
FROM `challenges` AS c
WHERE 
  c.`owner_id` <> 3 -- discard challenges that have user 3 as their owner
  AND c.`status` = 'pending'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( -- discard challenges that have user 3 as their competitor
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `challenges_competitors` AS cc
    WHERE 
      cc.`user_id` = 3 -- limit this query to return only rows where user 3 is a competitor
      AND cc.`challenge_id` = c.`id` -- join condition with challenges table
    );
```

Here's your modified **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b81/4)**.

To get the entire set of columns that you have attached in your query you could keep the joins, as @xQbert suggested in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302218/return-a-set-of-sql-results-based-on-criteria-from-other-tables/35302419?noredirect=1#comment58315266_35302419).

```
SELECT *
FROM `challenges` c
LEFT JOIN `challenges_competitors` cc
  ON cc.`challenge_id` = c.`id`
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.`id` = cc.`user_id`
WHERE 
  c.`owner_id` != 3 
  AND c.`status` = 'pending'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM `challenges_competitors` cc2
    WHERE cc.`id` = cc2.`id` and cc2.`user_id` = 3
  )
ORDER BY c.`id`;
```

Comment: Well done.  Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b81/6/0) that still contains the user and challenges joins incase the OP needs information from those tables.

Comment: Thanks for your addition. I've included it in the answer, if that's OK with you.

Comment: Thanks for this! :) Running it on my database it works wonders, now gonna have to play around with my code to make sure this gets interpreted well by FuelPHP. hehe.

Comment: @ConsiderMe it's all good!  I added it as a comment as I believed your answer addressed the specific question: "return any challenge that user3 does not own or is part of  you return the challenges;" but I wondered why the joins in the first place so just in case...  Though fiddles don't survive for ever, if you want to copy and paste the SQL from the fiddle that's fine by me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because owner is also a row in the user table you need to include the user table as an alias. I'm not quite sure what you need to get back - I don't understand exactly what the question is, but you should be able to add a where clause to this to get what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM `challenges`
 JOIN `challenges_competitors` ON `challenges_competitors`.`challenge_id` = `challenges`.`id`
 JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `challenges_competitors`.`user_id`
 JOIN `users` AS `owners` ON `owners`.`id` = `challenges`.`owner_id`
```